# Pass a string to a Listener from a Service

Tags: android, string, listener

I currently have a Service. This service (when active) starts a PhoneCallListener (overriden by me) and then basically listens to phone calls. 
Before I access my Service, I have a String which I pass to my service.
This all works great, but how can I pass the String I have to my listener? I wasn't able to create any context or anything. My code:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.isActive = true;
        this.phoneNum = intent.getStringExtra("num");
        Toast.makeText(this, phoneNum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        otherFunc();
        return mStartMode;
    }
    private void otherFunc() {
        PhoneCallListener phoneCallListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }




class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    String phoneNumToIgnore = "";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            isPhoneCalling = true;

            /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE EXTRA STRING*/

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, looks like you are trying to pass the phone number to ignore to listener from onStartCommand(). Why not pass that number to otherFunc(string num) and then create a constructor on Phonelistener to initialize the phone listener with it?

Comment: One of the moments I think how the hell I didn't see this before. THANKS!